# How to stop \n becoming \r\n in php

Tags: php

I have a php script that creates a text file:

```
<?php
$f = fopen("x.mrg","wt");
fwrite($f,"testing\n123\n");
fclose($f);
?>
```

When I look at the output file in a hex editor, the `\n` has been changed to `\r\n` (0D 0A)

Complete hex output:

```
74 65 73 74 69 6E 67 0D 0A 31 32 33 0D 0A    testing..123..
```

How do I stop it doing that?  Is there an ini file setting for this?

I'm using php 5.6.7 on windows 8.1

I'm using HxD to view the hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows differentiates between text and binary files. You are currently open the file in text mode using `t`. You need to open the file using `b` for *binary mode* instead:

```
$f = fopen("x.mrg","wb");
```

Check the [notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#refsect1-function.fwrite-notes) in the manual page of `fwrite()`.

Comment: The file is where it was created